# Can't connect to WLAN with netctl

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, raspberry-pi, netctl

I can't connect to a WiFi network. I tried various methods such as `wpa_supplicant` and `wicd`. At the moment I'm trying `netctl`.

When I enter the command: `systemctl --type=service` I see the following errors:

[image]

**netctl start wireless-home**

```
Job for netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service failed. See 'systemctl status
netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

This is the profile file for `wireless-home`:

```
Description='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
IP=dhcp
ESSID='Pruthenia 3.OG'
Key='XXXXXXXXXX'
```

**systemctl status netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service**

```
netctl@wirelessx2dhome.service - Networking for netctl profile wirelessx2dhome 
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static) 
Active: inactive (dead) Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
```

**journalctl -xn output -->**

```
Dec 12 08:01:01 webcampi CROND[2765]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 09:01:01 webcampi crond[3490]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 12 09:01:01 webcampi CROND[3491]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 09:01:01 webcampi CROND[3490]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 10:01:01 webcampi crond[4216]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 12 10:01:01 webcampi CROND[4217]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 10:01:01 webcampi CROND[4216]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 11:01:01 webcampi crond[4941]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 12 11:01:01 webcampi CROND[4942]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 11:01:01 webcampi CROND[4941]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your journal output are useless: crond is used by your system to schedule task. Not related to your problem. I guess your interface name is wrong. Are you sure you need the single quotes around your ESSID and key? If all fails, try directly wpa_supplicant and dhcp. These will be more verbose.

Comment: Yes i am sure that the inteface name is correct wpa_supplicant is working though to thigs are add, i cant get dhcp working and wpa_supplicant stopps working afther a few minutes, that why i wanted to switch to netctl

Comment: netctl is using wpa_supplicant and dhcpd. Solve your problem with them first and then netctl should work as expected.

Comment: Try to remove the hyphen from the name of your profile, e.g. rename it for example to `wirelesshome`. There's [notice about it in archwiki page about `netctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#Configuration) (that's also `netctl`'s wiki, because `netctl` is arch project).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely due to [`netctl` not liking hyphens in its profile files.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#Configuration)

Excerpt from there:

> **Tip:** As [mentioned](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1311864/) in the forums, because [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) treats hyphens in a special way, using '-' in a profile name may result in connection drop issues.

Another excerpt (this has value only if you have created your profile file with `wifi-menu -o`):

> **Warning:** Attempting to use `wifi-menu -o` to generate a profile file in `/etc/netctl/` with a '-' in name will likely fail. Renaming the file is recommended

As a solution, I'd suggest you to remove the hyphen from the name of your profile file, so the name of the profile file would end up to be for example `wirelesshome` or `wireless_home`.

After you've done that, you should be able to start your profile with `netctl start wirelesshome` (or whatever the profile name is), and then enable it (if you want it to start at boot) with `netctl enable wirelesshome`. Also, if you have enabled your previous profile file before, remember to disable it before enabling the new profile with `netctl disable wireless-home`.

Answer (score 1):

Make you sure you have the right interface. Check with

```
ip link
```

A procedure that often works for me to fix some problems is (change interface and my_profile to match your setup):

```
sudo ip link set *interface* down
netctl stop-all
netctl start my_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with `wifi-menu` and if you get it to work; save the config with `wifi-menu -o`. [netctl wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl)